# Connect Physical NIC to ESXi Distributed Port Group

Tags: networking, virtualization, esxi

I have a Virtual Distributed Switch set up to create a series of layer 2 networks.  Each of these networks is implemented as a VLAN and Distributed Port Group on the VDS.  What I would like to do is connect a physical machine to some of these networks.

Using a standard switch, I could connect a physical NIC to the switch by setting it as an interface on the VSS.  However, with the VDS I can't figure out how to do this - the only way to interact with a physical port appears to be as an Uplink, and these ports can only act as a VLAN trunk.

Is there a way to associate a physical NIC with a port in a Distributed Port Group?  If so, what are the search terms I should use?

The only option I can see right now is make a virtual machine route/bridge the traffic over to a VSS and associate the port there - but this seems like it should be overkill, and won't work for things like port mirroring to a physical device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a NIC to distributed vswitch not to a port group

Here is the [link](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-8D0F38FE-E08A-420D-9236-5980323E25D6.html) to configure it. If the port groups are using tagged vlans you should configure the NIC accordingly.

Comment: I can add the NIC to the distributed vswitch as an uplink, but I can only configure the port as a VLAN trunk - is there a way to connect them directly to a certain VLAN?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to connect a physical NIC to a vSwitch or Distributed vSwitch *except* as an uplink. Clearly this is not what you need.

However, I have thought up a hackish workaround: use a VM as a bridge.

Assuming you want to access traffic on the port group "VM Network", and that it's connected to vSwitch0 (which is connected to NIC0), create a new vSwitch (vSwitch1) connected to your auxiliary NIC (in this example NIC1) and a new Port Group for that vSwitch (called "Auxiliary NIC Bridge").

Now all you need is a VM to act as a simple network bridge between "VM Network" and "Auxiliary NIC Bridge". I assume you could do this in any *nix of your choosing; I have a couple router firmware VMs that get used for testing.

So here's the topology:

Auxiliary NIC -> vSwitch1 -> "Auxiliary NIC Bridge" -> Bridging VM -> "VM Network" -> vSwitch0

I've run a similar setup to great success: virtualized router, bridging two vSwitches, to provide network uplink on NIC0 and auxiliary hardlink on NIC1. I also ran DHCP for the whole thing, including VM Network, the ESXi host itself (major cringe; gotta configure static connection, set up autostart, then on reboot wait for the router VM to boot and provide the ESXi host with DHCP), and the auxiliary NIC. This was for a highly portable media server application that needed to work under a variety of networking conditions (e.g. when the uplink is single ethernet or WiFi and needs to be shared with subnet clients)